# Simple iPhone jailbreak tweak not working

Tags: iphone, ios7, jailbreak, logos

```
#import <UIKit/UIAlertView.h>

@class NSObject;

@interface SBIconController : NSObject
+ (SBIconController *)sharedInstance;
- (BOOL)isEditing;
@end

%hook SBIconController
-(void)iconTapped:(id)tapped {
    SBIconController *sbic = [objc_getClass("SBIconController") sharedInstance];
    if ([sbic isEditing]) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message"  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tapped] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
    }
    %orig;
}
%end
```

Above is a simple tweak that I have created with Logos. For some reason after installing, nothing is working, I just can't figure out what the problem is and How can I solve this problem?

Other questions that I have are:

- Why do we declare class like `SBIconController` when there's already a `SBIconController` class?
- Why do we declare it as a subclass of `NSObject`?
- Why don't we just type in SBIconController when we're calling the `[SBIconController sharedInstance]` instead of `[objc_getClass("SBIconController") sharedInstance]`?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine. I tested it (I don't use logos) and `iconTapped:` method is indeed called when you tap an app icon. But what are you trying to achieve with `isEditing`? This property indicates whether you are editing SpringBoard (tap and hold an app icon) and when it equals `YES` method `iconTapped:` is NOT called when icon is tapped. It's called only when `isEditing` equals `NO`. So I suggest you insert alert without `if ([sbic isEditing])` to test whether your tweak is working.

As for your other questions:

1. When dealing with private APIs we don't have headers and will get warnings/errors if we try to use them. In your case it's `SBIconController`. To solve this problem we can either download headers that others dumped using various tools like class-dump or declare these private APIs yourself. In your case it's latter.
2. Because `SBIconController` inherits from `NSObject`.
3. You can do it either way. Of course, when you have class declaration you don't need to use `objc_getClass`. And in your case you don't even need either of this things. You can just use `self` like you would in any other obj-C method. Your code will look like this:

   ```
   %hook SBIconController
   -(void)iconTapped:(id)tapped {
       if ([self isEditing]) {
           UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message"  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tapped] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [alertView show];
           [alertView release];
       }
       %orig;
   }
   %end
   ```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I use isEditing to check if the springboard is in edit mode or "wiggle mode" or not